# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes (Kubuntu) with google meet call. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, google-chrome, freeze

My Ubuntu 20.04 freezes every 2nd or 3rd  - 1 hr call, that leaves me to hard restart / reset my system almost everyday, and I lose all the tabs and settings for the day.

These are the last lines in /var/log/syslog -

** NOTE: Replaced logs to more relevant logs as mentioned below**

```
Jun  9 12:03:29 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2715]: message repeated 14 times: [ fct_update_tray_menu was called by Wnck::Screen=HASH(0x5642d1e56d58)]
Jun  9 12:05:01 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[25308]: [25302:25302:0609/120501.832826:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
Jun  9 12:06:02 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2525]: kdeinit5: PID 56552 terminated.
Jun  9 12:06:02 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2525]: kdeinit5: PID 56555 terminated.
Jun  9 12:06:02 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2525]: kdeinit5: PID 56554 terminated.
Jun  9 12:06:09 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2592]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 27633, resource id: 148897803, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Jun  9 12:06:09 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2525]: kdeinit5: PID 56579 terminated.
Jun  9 12:06:09 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2525]: kdeinit5: PID 56578 terminated.
Jun  9 12:06:09 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2525]: kdeinit5: PID 56580 terminated.
Jun  9 12:06:25 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
Jun  9 12:06:26 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <warn>  [1686308785.9296] sup-iface[0x55b07c400210,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jun  9 12:06:26 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[25308]: [25302:25332:0609/120626.626966:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Jun  9 12:06:26 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=04:70:56:69:8b:f0 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Jun  9 12:06:26 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308786.0091] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jun  9 12:06:26 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jun  9 12:06:26 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308786.0092] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jun  9 12:06:27 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308786.0093] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun  9 12:06:27 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308786.0094] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun  9 12:06:27 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2656]: powerdevil: Releasing inhibition with cookie  622
Jun  9 12:06:27 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2656]: powerdevil: Can't contact ck
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16 (SSID='LolipopWireless24' freq=5180 MHz)
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap kernel: [96645.512116] wlp2s0: authenticate with e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap kernel: [96645.514167] wlp2s0: send auth to e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16 (try 1/3)
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap kernel: [96645.515182] wlp2s0: authenticated
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap kernel: [96645.518827] wlp2s0: associate with e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16 (try 1/3)
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap kernel: [96645.520674] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=5)
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap kernel: [96645.521902] wlp2s0: associated
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16 (SSID='LolipopWireless24' freq=5180 MHz)
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308789.3198] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: Associated with e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308789.3198] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> associating
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308789.3211] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308789.3211] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308789.3376] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308789.3377] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308789.3999] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1686308789.4138] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=585100
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap kernel: [96645.630773] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 19 (20 - 1) dBm as advertised by e4:75:dc:e3:ed:16
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap wpa_supplicant[901]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=585100
Jun  9 12:06:29 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2656]: powerdevil: Scheduling inhibition from ":1.877" "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable" with cookie 626 and reason "Playing audio"
Jun  9 12:06:34 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2656]: powerdevil: Enforcing inhibition from ":1.877" "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable" with cookie 626 and reason "Playing audio"
Jun  9 12:06:34 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2656]: powerdevil: Added interrupt session
Jun  9 12:06:34 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2656]: powerdevil: Can't contact ck
Jun  9 12:06:41 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[25308]: [54060:14:0609/120641.205822:ERROR:srtp_transport.cc(216)] Failed to unprotect RTP packet: size=128, seqnum=9383, SSRC=6666, previous failure count: 200
Jun  9 12:07:32 lolipop-lap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2525]: kdeinit5: PID 56557 terminated.
```

I am sure of the above log lines, as I restarted this laptop after it froze only after about 2 hours so the timestamp makes sense.
Could anyone decipher these lines for me please, and tell me whats wrong?  What Could I fix (which driver etc?).

I understand that this could be because google chrome fails, but why does the whole system have freeze, and what can I do for Linux to recover with just chrome failing?

```
kurudi@lolipop-lap:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

And Kubuntu DDE version

```
kurudi@lolipop-lap:~$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.18.8
```

Comment: Don't post logvomit. Post a tiny relevant fragment. In your case, the avtual problem is earlier in the log. Your first message at `12:07:32` is part of the post failure cleanup. Read `man journalctl` and use `journalctl` to look at logs. Page through the log, look for a gap in timestamps just before `12:07:32`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Re- pasting logvomit...  my problem was that I didnt know what to read on ubuntu logs, so I took the last 3 mins of the log and pasted.

Comment: @waltinator, now I have updated the above logs to 1 more minute before 12:07 - could you let me know what exactly has happened here? is this a combination of wifi disconnection and google chrome issue at the same time ?

(Once we identify the relevant logs for this issue, I will reduce the log lines in question above to only specific ones, and remove the rest.)

Comment: Guess, its not obvious for anyone why the system froze with any logs... This behaviour is very much simulatable / repeatable and hence there should be some bug which it hits.  Will leave it here then ...

Comment: The system crashed once more today after just 30 mins of a google meet call. When comparing entries from syslog,  this line repeats before every crash - "powerdevil: Scheduling inhibition from ":1.896" "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable" with cookie 596 and reason "Playing audio""

Could this be the reason for my system crashes?

Comment: You have both `wlp2s0` and `p2p-dev-wlp2s0` trying to configure the same hardware, and interfering with each other. Pick one